# Property Injection with internal setter

Tags: properties, autofac, internal

I have an existing application that I am modifying to use Autofac Property Injection.  It seems regardless of which method I use to register my types with properties, the properties are always null unless they have public setters.  With other IoC containers (e.g. Structuremap) it's possible to scope the setter internal and make it available using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute on the assembly.  This would seem nice to restrict clients from modifying the assignment.

Is this possible with Autofac? Or is there another approach when working with property injection to keep the assignments secure?

I've tried using reflection with `PropertiesAutoWired()` as well as resolving `.WithParameter()` from my WebApi Global.asax - specifying the specific parameter to be set with no success as an internal setter.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyWebAPI.dll")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Autofac.dll")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Autofac.Configuration.dll")]
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class BaseContext
    {
        public MyPublicClass _dbHelper { get; internal set; }

        public BaseContext()
        {

        }

        protected string DbConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return _dbHelper.DbConn; //<-Always null unless setter is public
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot inject `internal` setters with autofac, because the `AutowiringPropertyInjector` class is only looking for public properties (see [source](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/AutowiringPropertyInjector.cs)).

However a logic in the `AutowiringPropertyInjector` is very simple so you can create your own version which does injection for non public properties:

```cs
public static class AutowiringNonPublicPropertyInjector
{
     public static void InjectProperties(IComponentContext context, 
            object instance, bool overrideSetValues)
     {
          if (context == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
          if (instance == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
          foreach (
             PropertyInfo propertyInfo in 
                 //BindingFlags.NonPublic flag added for non public properties
                 instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                  BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.NonPublic))
         {
             Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
             if ((!propertyType.IsValueType || propertyType.IsEnum) &&
                 (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 &&
                     context.IsRegistered(propertyType)))
             {
                 //Changed to GetAccessors(true) to return non public accessors
                 MethodInfo[] accessors = propertyInfo.GetAccessors(true);
                 if ((accessors.Length != 1 || 
                     !(accessors[0].ReturnType != typeof (void))) &&
                      (overrideSetValues || accessors.Length != 2 ||
                      propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null) == null))
                 {
                     object obj = context.Resolve(propertyType);
                     propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, obj, null);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can use this class in the `OnActivated` event

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyPublicClass>();
builder.RegisterType<BaseContext>()
    .OnActivated(args =>   
          AutowiringNonPublicPropertyInjector
              .InjectProperties(args.Context, args.Instance, true));
```

However the above listed solution now injects all kind of properties so even private and protected ones so you may need to extend it with some additional checks to make sure that you will only inject the properties what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a solution like this:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MyPublicClass>();
builder.RegisterType<BaseContext>()
       .OnActivating(CustomPropertiesHandler);
```

With a handler like this:

```cs
//If OnActivated: Autofac.Core.IActivatedEventArgs
public void CustomPropertiesHandler<T>(Autofac.Core.IActivatingEventArgs<T> e)
{
    var props = e.Instance.GetType()
        .GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties //Also "private prop" with "public set"
        .Where(pi => pi.CanWrite) //Has a set accessor.
        //.Where(pi => pi.SetMethod.IsPrivate) //set accessor is private
        .Where(pi => e.Context.IsRegistered(pi.PropertyType)); //Type is resolvable

    foreach (var prop in props)
        prop.SetValue(e.Instance, e.Context.Resolve(prop.PropertyType), null);
}
```

Since both IActivatingEventArgs and IActivatedEventArgs has instance and context, you might want to use wrapping methods that uses those parameters on CustomPropertiesHandler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can write @nemesv implementation as an extension method.

```
public static class AutofacExtensions
{
    public static void InjectProperties(IComponentContext context, object instance, bool overrideSetValues)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (instance == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(instance));
        }

        foreach (var propertyInfo in instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                      BindingFlags.Public |
                                                                      BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

            if ((!propertyType.IsValueType || propertyType.IsEnum) && (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0) && context.IsRegistered(propertyType))
            {
                var accessors = propertyInfo.GetAccessors(true);
                if (((accessors.Length != 1) ||
                     !(accessors[0].ReturnType != typeof(void))) &&
                    (overrideSetValues || (accessors.Length != 2) ||
                     (propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null) == null)))
                {
                    var obj = context.Resolve(propertyType);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, obj, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle> InjectPropertiesAsAutowired<TLimit, TActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle>(
        this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle> registration)
    {
        return registration.OnActivated(args => InjectProperties(args.Context, args.Instance, true));
    }
```

To Use;

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<StartupConfiguration>().As<IStartupConfiguration>().AsSelf().InjectPropertiesAsAutowired().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current [version of Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/) defined optional `IPropertySelector` parameter for `PropertiesAutowired` which is used to [filter out injectable properties](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/41044d7d1a4fa277c628021537d5a12016137c3b/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/AutowiringPropertyInjector.cs#L88).

default implementation for `IPropertySelector` is [DefaultPropertySelector](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/5a6b790114dab4da141243abc6d39cab3f9024d8/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/DefaultPropertySelector.cs), which filters non public properties.

```
public virtual bool InjectProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object instance)
{
   if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite || propertyInfo.SetMethod?.IsPublic != true)
   {
       return false;
   }
   ....
 }
```

define custom `IPropertySelector` which allows injection to non public properties

```
public class AccessRightInvariantPropertySelector : DefaultPropertySelector
{
    public AccessRightInvariantPropertySelector(bool preserveSetValues) : base(preserveSetValues)
    { }

    public override bool InjectProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object instance)
    {
        if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!PreserveSetValues || !propertyInfo.CanRead)
        {
            return true;
        }
        try
        {
            return propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null) == null;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Issue #799: If getting the property value throws an exception
            // then assume it's set and skip it.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use

```
builder.RegisterType<AppService>()
      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
      .PropertiesAutowired(new AccessRightInvariantPropertySelector(true));
```

**Alternatively**

*Install*

```
PM> Install-Package Autofac.Core.NonPublicProperty
```

*Use*

```
builder.RegisterType<AppService>()
      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
      .AutoWireNonPublicProperties();
```

Comment: I just tried to install Autofac.Core.NonPublicProperty, it brings an insane amount of dependencies which to me seems completely unmotivated. Things like cryptography etc. Also doesn't work when running. Not recommended.

Comment: @jool are you sure ? it only bring `Autofac (4.5.0)` nothing more. [check image](https://ibb.co/gMUVEw)

Comment: @tchelidze I'm having the same issue. My project targets .NET Framework (net472) and because your code targets .NET Standard, all kinds of System.* packages are installed. Is there a way to avoid that?